# The API is being very standoffish

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

I was working on [Blaze](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/Blaze) and noticed that I was getting quite a few of those nasty backoff violations. I checked my code for infinite loops and whatnot, then checked the dev console.

Here's the timeline:

1. I call `/answers` with my key and a pagesize of 100. The exact path I call:

   ```
   https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?page=1&pagesize=100&key=p3YZ1qDutpcBd7Bte2mcDw((&site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=creation&filter=!LeJQlFEfIbsDDTG1lReSJX
   ```
2. I get back a 10 second backoff parameter. On the first call. (I'm not hammering it, this is the first time I opened it today)
3. I allow the user to disregard it (because I'm too lazy to build in a backoff checker gizmo) and the API hates me.

I don't really think that calling `/answers` should send a backoff on the first time. Sources also say that `/posts` does the same thing, but can't be repro'd on `/questions`.

**Edit**: Upon further testing, it seems I can only repro this behavior when making calls against Stack Overflow.

**Another edit**: I can repro this on [this simple API call in the console](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#pagesize=1&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) - where I'm only asking for the *single* most recent answer, and I get a 10s backoff on the first try. This can't be right.

Comment: This is best asked on http://StackApps.com, the site for API support and applications built with the API.

Comment: Hey; if you stepped up too close to me too often, I'd tell you to stand back, too! ;)

Comment: How many first calls have you made, actually, and in what time-frame?

Comment: Heh. @JanDvorak My first call today got a backoff. My first call yesterday got a backoff. And the day before that. Also, Tim Stone repro'd. Usually I make ~20 calls/day. These 'first calls' happened after at least 10 hours of silence.

Comment: any chance you're on a shared IP?

Comment: Very little, @JanDvorak. And Tim repro'd, so the chances of *both* of us being on an IP with a crazy-API-abuser-guy are... insanely low.

Comment: Hmm... I'm sending cca 200 requests per day to /answers/.../ and I'm yet to see a backoff. Could there be less backoff for anonymous apps than for registered ones?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason you're getting so much backoff is that you're ignoring it... it exists for a reason

Comment: @Doorknob Doubtful. I should hope the API doesn't have a memory that lasts ten hours saying "give this guy a backoff every time"

Comment: More exactly, I'm fetching answers by question ID. But if you're fetching answers from the entire site, it doesn't make sense to pull the same page over and over again faster than the server cache refreshes.

Comment: That's... beside the point, @JanDvorak. Blaze is really meant to be as thin a window into the API as possible while still looking fairly decent. It's up to the user when to refresh. And getting a 10-second backoff right off the bat isn't right.

Comment: "*If an application receives a response with the backoff field set, it must wait that many seconds before hitting the same method again....Note that backoff is set based on a combination of factors, and may not be consistently returned for the same arguments to the same method.*" - does this text from the throttle page of the API not address your concerns?  Your not doing what it says to do.

Comment: @jadarnel I would suggest you use Blaze. And many of the other people that are saying similar things. It's... a different kind of app. And the 'you're not doing what it says' argument holds no water if it's the first call of the day.

Comment: Why does it hold no water?  The docs say "...it *must* wait that many seconds."  There's no "if it's the first call of the day" or "if it's a...different kind of app."

Comment: You shouldn't disregard the backoff. It's not really something you agree or disagree with.

Comment: @AnnaLear While that's true (shame on Undo), it really doesn't make sense that the API considers this specific operation so much more expensive than all the others. *Something* must not be right there.

Comment: @TimStone The backoff is based (in part) on the time it takes to run a particular query. On the site the size of Stack Overflow, it's conceivable that it'd be expensive. It doesn't matter if it's your first query of the day of 1,000th.

Comment: @AnnaLear It's not really conceivable that requesting the last `n` records of the posts table is somehow more expensive than requesting the last `n` records of the posts table which are also questions.

Comment: (On second thought it's not *completely* inconceivable, but I'm still skeptical)

Comment: @AnnaLear Can I get another look at this? It's still happening and it's really annoying.

Comment: @Undo Are you still running without respecting the backoff?

Comment: Respected it on this IP, @AnnaLear, for at least a week. Returning a backoff on the first query on /answers for only one site seems really really odd to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The API protects itself from heavy load to various subsystems that support it. In this case you were tripping a SQL server load throttle due to a very bad query plan due to a `PostTypeId = @Answer` rather than `PostTypeId = 2` that snuck in there.

This has been corrected, and the new `PostTypeId = {=Answer}` (Dapper literal replacement) is live. You should no longer see a backoff. To get an idea of how bad this was...

Old query:

```
Table 'Users'. Scan count 0, logical reads 404.
Table 'Posts'. Scan count 1, logical reads 156368.
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 8406 ms,  elapsed time = 9164 ms.
```

New query:

```
Table 'Users'. Scan count 0, logical reads 400.
Table 'Posts'. Scan count 1, logical reads 9460.
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 13 ms.
```

Your results should also now return *just* a tad bit faster.