# Stack Exchange API too many requests from this IP address

Tags: support, stack-exchange, api

I am using the Stack Exchange API to get Stack Overflow data, but I am getting "too many request from this ip" after making only five requests. I got JSON content like this:

```
{u'error_id': 502, u'error_message': u'too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 68492 seconds', u'error_name': u'throttle_violation'}
```

I made the following requests to Stack Exchange without an access token:

1. "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow" ---> 2 times called this API
2. "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?order=desc&min=1416268800&sort=activity&tagged=python&site=stackoverflow" --> 3 times called this API and on the 4th call I got an exception

Comment: Shared IP? Memory failure? A rogue loop in your code?

Comment: No loop in my code I am making one request at a time and IP is not shared

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be requesting the same URL twice in less than a minute. Also, have you got a backoff header?

Comment: but requesting twice in less than a minute is not mentioned in rate limiting https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle right ?

Comment: "While not strictly a throttle, the Stack Exchange API employs heavy caching and as such no application should make semantically identical requests more than once a minute. This is generally a waste of bandwidth as, more often than not, the exact same result will be returned." - last paragraph

Comment: Pure speculation:  they may have tightened up the rules after recent DDOS attack on SO. I suggest registering on Stack Apps to get a key for your application. You don't need to make anything about your code public there: the software automatically generates a private page for your app and gives you a key parameter.  Passing &key=... with your requests should solve the problem.

Comment: Related: [The API is being very standoffish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229958)

Answer (score 17):

It looks like you selectively read the [throttle guidance](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle)

> A dynamic throttle is also in place on a per-method level. If an application receives a response with the backoff field set, it must wait that many seconds before hitting the same method again. For the purposes of throttling, all /me routes are considered to be identical to their /users/{ids} equivalent. Note that backoff is set based on a combination of factors, and may not be consistently returned for the same arguments to the same method. Additionally, all methods (even seemingly trivial ones) may return backoff.

If I take your [first URL](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow) on my first response I immediately get a `backoff` for 10 seconds:

```
{ ... ,"has_more":true,
       "backoff":10,
       "quota_max":300,
       "quota_remaining":299}
```

So don't go down the route to guesstimate how many calls per minute you're allowed. Instead always honor the `backoff`.

Note that the `backoff` can be "undefined" (as in not present in the response) meaning you don't have to honor a backoff before your next call. But don't be abusive, keep it way under 30 requests per sec.

Make sure you have included the `backoff` field in your field selection:

[image: backoff field marked enabled in the field selection dialog]

Comment: This is the correct answer. If I recall correctly using a key also gives you less strict throttling, so register for one in case you can't actually meet this backoff period.

Comment: Unfortunately the API doesn't always return the `backoff` parameter and sometime just block without any explanation.

Comment: @this.lau_ yes, that is possible if you happen to be on an IP address that has many connections. You'll be blocked by the HA-proxy in that case with a 503 http error. You can recover from those by backing off for 60 seconds.