# API /answers route likes telling clients to back off

Tags: bug, api

Almost any request to /answers on Stack Overflow (including a single-post request, e.g. [this](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#pagesize=1&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)) results in a 10 second backoff, even if no recent requests have been made to the API. My guess is something similar to what happened in [The API is being very standoffish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229958/the-api-is-being-very-standoffish) has occurred -- some bad query plan has been generated, causing any request to yield a backoff.

Could someone please investigate and see why all the backoffs are being generated? Obviously, this isn't too important, but it would be nice not to have a backoff generated on every /answers request.

Comment: Something is wrong. Reload that doc page 3 times in 20 seconds and get a throttle_violation. . . .  BUT, if you use a `fromdate` (or similar restriction), the problem seems to go away.

Comment: Without technical knowledge, this would sound really weird.