# Unable to fetch data from the Stack Overflow API (too many requests)

Tags: discussion, support, api

I am trying to fetch API data from:
    [api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow...](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow)

But I am getting the error:

> {error_id: 502, error_message: "too many requests from this IP, more
>   requests available in 24527 seconds", error_name:
>   "throttle_violation"}

I saw this answer:
  [Stack Exchange API too many requests from this IP address](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243773/stack-exchange-api-too-many-requests-from-this-ip-address)

But, I'm not able to understand how to set `backoff` to 10. Do we have to edit it?

Is there some way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Not a bug, works fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

The `backoff` property is not something you set.  It is the number of seconds your app must wait before making another API call.

So, if you get `backoff: 10` in the response, **wait 10 seconds before calling the API again.**

However, it's not clear that that's the issue. Unlike [some other calls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229958/the-api-is-being-very-standoffish), the [call listed in your question](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow) does not automatically trigger a `backoff`.

**Is there any chance that you've just made more than 300 API calls in the last 24 hours?**

---

#### Steps to resolve:

1. Always, always, [always monitor the response for the `backoff`, `error_id`, `error_message`, `error_name`, and `quota_remaining` properties](https://stackapps.com/a/7832/7653).
2. Appropriately act on the above if they are present or if the `quota_remaining` gets close to zero.
3. [Register your app for an API key](https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work).  This allows you to have a 10K quota instead of 300.
4. [Send your API key with every API call](https://stackapps.com/questions/4699/how-to-make-a-stack-exchange-api-call-using-my-key) or POST.
5. Be aware of high "cost" API calls, as these are the ones most likely to trigger a `backoff`.  (See the warning at [the paging docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging) and also [Nick Craver's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244314/148310))